# How can I make sure that the image size gets bigger when clicking on a image, using lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor, lightbox

I am using a lightbox jquery plugin:

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html

The html looks like this:

```
<a href="@item.Imageurl" rel="shadowbox"> <img src="@item.Imageurl" alt ="@(item.Title)"/></a>
```

Basicly the image is 100px/100px, But I would like to make it 180px/180px when the image opens up in the lightbox modal when the thumbnail gets clicked, the thumbnail should still be 100px/100px How can I do that?

Comment: Make the href point to a bigger image

Comment: I cant change the images size since its a url I grab by xml the link to image is not my image. Is it possible to make the size bigger by another way?

Answer (score 0):

href should point to the full size image, img to the thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

You want to add width and height properties to the shadowbox element. From the documentation it looks like you'll add those properties in the following manner. 
$(document).ready(function () {
 Shadowbox.setup("a", {
        width: 180px,
        height: 180px
    });
});

Comment: t makes the modal bigger not the href link image